# Count number of failed attempts by user in Google ReCaptcha Puzzle

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, recaptcha, react-google-recaptcha, grecaptcha

Using the well-known library [React-Google-ReCaptcha] (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-recaptcha), we integrated Google reCaptcha into our React application. So, is there a method to track how many times users have tried to solve the Google ReCaptcha puzzle but have failed, or has anyone utilised this library to do so? For our analytics purposes, we actually need to know which user didn't attempt the challenge.

I try with package callbacks that is mentioned in description of package link. But unfortunately no callback is through on failed attempts.